# AWS elastic beanstalk log snapshot files

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, snapshot

How and where can I define what files are tailed in the snapshot that AWS Elastic Beanstalk takes from the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special configuration to define this, but all the files in /opt log folder is tailed.

For a python app, "/opt/python/log/" is the path where any file in this is tailed. You can identify this path by the presence of httpd.out in the same directory. If you need another file also to be tailed, then keep it too in this path.